# iOS layout images dynamically 

Tags: ios, layout

I'm trying to find a rational solution for a layout problem in iOS.

I need to load n images in a view with this layout:

```
-----------
|  x   x  |
|  x   x  |
|  x   x  |
|  x   x  |
|  x   x  |
|  x   x  |
-----------
```

Each image may have a different width, but the height has a maximum and each image is to be centered in it's column.

What is the suggested approach?

I'm thinking of putting views with 50% width side by side and then center the images in them.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont understand the down vote. Is this question not valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started.  It does not, however, take into consideration the ratio of the images.

```
CGRect  bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat maxCol = [imageViewArray count] + ([imageViewArray count] % 2);
CGFloat width  = (bounds.size.width/2) - 15;
CGFloat height = (bounds.size.height/maxCol) - 10; 

// loop through imageViews
for(pos = 0; pos < [imageViewArray count]; pos++)
{
   // calculate position within grid
   CGFloat row = (pos/2);
   CGFloat col = (pos%2);


   // retrieves UIImageView and UIImage
   imageView       = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:pos];
   image           = imageView.image;

   // calculates image size
   CGFloat scaledWidth = (height * image.size.width) / image.size.height;

   // adjust size of image view
   imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,            // temp value for x
                                0,            // temp value for y
                                height,       // width of image
                                scaledWidth); // height of image

   // adjust position of image view
   imageView.center = CGPointMake((bounds.size.width/3) + ((bounds.size.width/3) * col),
                                  ((height+10) * row) + (height+10)/2));

   // add image view to super view
   [rootView addSubView:imageView];
};
```

The above scaling assumes that the height of the grid location is always smaller than the width of the grid location.

Comment: thanks, I tried your code, and yes it seems to be right on track.

Answer (score 2):

If you will load a lot of images it will cause performance problems. Better way to do this - use `UITableView` with [custom cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).

Comment: Yes, its an option, but is'nt it weird to have two itens on a datasource bound to each row?

Comment: No. What is weird? Also if i talk about performance: you can load images from filesystem in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I'm new to iOS dev, and my understanding was that the concept of a uitableview was to have a datasource and bind one item to each row. That's why I was saying it felt weird to bind two elements from the datasource to each row. But if its ok, then it is definitely a option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the same problem a text engine has when rendering glyphs. What you want to do is to first calculate the width for a row before you do anything else. This is done by looping from left to right, adding the sizes of the views until you get to the edge and can't add more. Then you know the width and the maximum height for that row, and simply center the views by adding an offset to the left equal to the margin that was left to the right divided by two. And then add an offset to the y coordinate by the maximum height for that row.

Then simply keep doing that for all views until they are all have a position.

Comment: Either I did'nt understand your suggestion, or you did'nt understand my problem. I know the number of views in a row (2). So in an iphone each column is going to have 160 of width, my problem is that inside each column I need to center the image.